# What RFCs need to be considered in developing a POP3 client?

Tags: pop3, rfc

In theory, the set of Request For Comments (RFC) contain everything that a developer needs to know to build a POP3 client. However, it is not always easy to know which RFCs need to be considered and which ones can be ignored.

Does anyone have an RFC roadmap to steer developers through this? By RFC roadmap, I mean:

- A complete list of RFCs that need to
  be read and understood, in order to
  develop a POP3 client.
- An indication of which RFCs no longer
  need to be considered, because they
  have been superseded.
- A summary of the relevant RFCs.
- Detail on how the relevant RFCs
  interrelate to each other.
- An indication of the logical order to
  read and understand the relevant
  RFCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wikipedia [pop3 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) seems to contain all this information:

> POP (POP1) is specified in RFC 918, POP2 by RFC 937. The original specification of POP3 is RFC 1081. Its current specification is RFC 1939, updated with an extension mechanism, RFC 2449 and an authentication mechanism in RFC 1734.